# .css files in root folder don't load in _Layout in ASP.NET Core MVC web app

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm fairly new to ASP.NET Core MVC web apps, and stumbled upon a problem with my loading `.css` files in my `_Layout.cshtml`.

My application is a standard MVC app with a SQL database, 3 controllers `HomeController`, `StudentsController` and `CommunitiesController` for each corresponding view folder.

The controllers and views for `Student` and `Community` are generated scaffolded items. And in the `Views` folder of each of these models are `Index.cshtml` along with other CRUD cshtml files just as expected.

However, the css file referenced in the `_Layout.cshtml` only works for `Index.cshtml` of each folder - but not in the CRUD views nor the Index with ID parameters so going to `Home/Index` or `Student/Index` will have the css styling applied, but `Student/Edit`, `Community/Index/{id}` will not have the css files applied.

Here's my `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - School Community</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("site.css")"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
    <link href="@Url.Content("bootstrap.min.css")"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
 <! -- the rest of my common layout here -->
    
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

I have also checked the pages source and confirmed that those 2 `<link/>` tags are included, even in the problematic pages. I run this on localhost and I'm not sure if it is because of this that the bootstrap won't work, but the homepage is stylized as expected. Here's also the sample program that my professor provided : http://afrasialab4.azurewebsites.net/. You can refer to this to see the expected styling. The `@RenderSection` at the end is because the CRUD views use JavaScript.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try to clear the browser cache and check whether the issue disappears or not. If not working, for the problematic pages, try to use F12 developer Elements tools to check whether the page contains the css reference link and whether the html element contains CSS style or not. Besides, use F12 Console and Network tools to check if there have any error and whether the css file load success (I checked the provided sample, the css style works well, but you didin't add the JQuery reference in the layout page, see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEC5r.gif)).

Comment: Where is the `site.css` and `bootstrap.min.css` file? Generally, the static files are stored in the "wwwroot" folder, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09s8R.png), so when we add the CSS or JS reference in the layout page, the link should as below: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />`, see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox9Ef.png). If still not working, can you share your application via Github or OneDrive?

Comment: Thank you @ZhiLv, I just looked into the _Layout and discovered that I had put the path incorrectly. I changed it from just the css file names into "~/{file name}.css" and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to the views you want to have the same css and layout. If the Layout information is different, create another Layout file and enter only the information you want. If you make another Layout, change this code to the name of the New Layout.

```html
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index Students";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutName.cshtml";
}
```

Comment: Oh, but I have already specified the _Layout to be used in _ViewStart.cshtml. The thing is, _Layout works as the <header></header> from it is included in every pages. It's just that the css are not loaded in some of the pages.

Comment: Hi, maybe I didn't understand you correctly. To verify that css is being generated for the page you want, check your page's source code. What may be happening is an overwrite by the classes you are using. I had these problems too, I had to re-declare the css code in the html <style> on each page, I know it's not the best practice, but it worked for me.